# Python sqlite3 assertion error

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, pycharm, bottle

I am pretty sure the code I am doing is logical and makes sense but when I run it against my test the result comes back quite unusual, I am trying find a session from a cookie, and then use it to retrieve the user from the sessions table. I am using the bottle framework to test my program

```
    active_session = bottle.request.get_cookie(COOKIE_NAME)
cursor = db.cursor()

if active_session:
    cursor.execute("SELECT usernick FROM sessions WHERE sessionid=?", (active_session, ))
    active_user = cursor.fetchone()
    return active_user
else:
    return None
```

The result is as follows

```
    self.assertEqual(nick_from_cookie, nick)
AssertionError: ('Bobalooba',) != 'Bobalooba'\
```

I know I am so close could someone point me in the right direction

Comment: try `active_user = cursor.fetchone()[0]`

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable :( , i have tried this

Comment: ...that implies that the cursor you are using returns None for fetchone in the event there is no match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if active_session:
    cursor.execute("SELECT usernick FROM sessions WHERE sessionid=?", (active_session, ))
    active_user = cursor.fetchone()
    return active_user[0] if active_user else active_user
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are fetching the entire row and comparing it to a single string. You need to grab the single field contained in the retrieved row. Try this as the input to your assertion.

```
return active_user[0]
```

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable